# GAE - Can't obtain content in request

Tags: python, google-app-engine, post, http-post, webapp2

I'm using google app engine with python and webapp2. (I'm new with all these technologies)
I'm sending JSON from client to server.

Server:

```
class SetupAppHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        localdata = self.request.get('mydata')
        print("LocalData: " + localdata)
```

Client:

```
import requests,json

url = "http://localhost:8080/setupapp"
data = {'mydata': [14,17]}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)

print(r.content)
```

And `localdata` seems to be empty.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use json_data = self.request.body in your post handler to get the json. Your mydata key in in the json. data = json.loads(json_data) localdata = data['mydata']

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
request.POST["mydata"]
```

vs:

```
request.get("mydata")
```

I believe there's even some webapp2 middleware that allows you to:

```
request.JSON['mydata']
```

Comment: Maybe folks down-voted this answer because they haven't seen the webapp2 request documentation:  https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html.  Read the section "POST data"